# Bags allowed for India to Europe (Turkish Airlines) and back (Jet Airways)

Tags: luggage, turkish-airlines, jet-airways

I'm flying to Venice from Bombay using Turkish Airlines, my baggage allowance is 30kgs for check-in. 
Similarly I'm flying to Bombay from Munich using Jet Airways and baggage allowance is 30Kgs for check-in.
Nothing is mentioned in either tickets about the no. of bags allowed.

I want to know if I can carry 2 bags for check-in , which sum up to 30kgs or do I need to check-in only 1 bag which weighs 30kgs?

Answer (score 2):

I flew Etihad to New Delhi a couple of years back with the Abu Dhabi to New Delhi leg being on Jet Airways.

On the way I took two bags which was absolutely fine, both bags made it to Delhi.  However on the way back Jet Airways refused to allow me to check two separate bags in and claimed it was a max of one and wouldn't budge.

Long story short I had to get my bags wrapped together in one of those cellophane wrap machines, cost about 30 rupees and made me look like an idiot walking back to the check in desk :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kev
Btw, those cellophane wrap machines now cost about Rs. 250

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Turkish Airlines said :

Turkish Airlines does not have piece concept for European sectors it is only for US/Canada & African sectors.
Since your travelling to Venice, free baggage allowance is 30kgs on the ticket  the maximum weight of 1 piece cannot exceed 32kgs, Yes you can distribute 30kgs into 2 or 3 bags.
Cabin Baggage (Hand Baggage) is defined as any baggage of 8 kg and 55x40x23 cm, laptop bag can be carried separately.